# Download "disguised" file using a PyQT scraper

Tags: python, jsf, download, web-scraping, pyqt

Well hello.

I'm having a hard time scraping a website using PyQT. The thing is, the site uses JSF, and the URL is the same for everything in this. Let's use "http://somesi.te/searchData.jsf" in this example.

I open it, fill a form (the target is the same URL), submit, and get the results in the same page. Up until there my script is working fine.

But the results return like 1000 paginated pages, and there is an anchor tag at the bottom to download an Excel file with all the results in a single file. 
This anchor is #-targeted, with the onClick event calling a MoJarra function, jsfcljs:

```
<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('formX'),{'formX:j_idt999':'formX:j_idt999'},'');return false">
```

Analyzing the function, it simply appends a `<input type="hidden">` in the form, and submit it again, presumably for the server to understand it and send me the Excel file instead of the web page.

The problem is: the server returns the file "disguised" as the web page. The URL is still "somesi.te/searchData.jsf", and the browsers recognize it as a file because of the headers.

And when I try using the unsupportedContent() to get the file, it seems like it don't follow the stream, it just try to fetch the URL received in the unsupportedContent signal. Being the current URL "somesi.te/searchData.jsf", when I save the file, I get the source code of the page, instead of getting my file.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
def getTicketDetails(self):
    self.webView.loadFinished.disconnect(self.getTicketDetails)

    self.webView.page().setForwardUnsupportedContent(True)
    self.webView.page().unsupportedContent.connect(self.downloadExcel)

    downloadButton = documentElement.findFirst('input[id="force_download"]')
    downloadButton.evaluateJavaScript("this.click();")    

def downloadExcel(self, reply):
    self.manager = self.webView.page().networkAccessManager()

    self.manager.finished.connect(self.saveExcel)

    postData = QByteArray()

    postData.append("formX=formX&")
    postData.append("formX:idSelecao_input=1&")
    postData.append("formX:dataJanela_input=03/11/2015&")
    postData.append("formX:dataAte_input=07/11/2015&")
    postData.append("formX:j_idt106_input=all&")
    postData.append("formX:j_idt120_input=0&")
    postData.append("formX:produto_input=VLR&")
    postData.append("formX:options=1&")
    postData.append("formX:j_idt133_input=0&")
    #postData.append("javax.faces.ViewState=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&")
    postData.append("formX:j_idt999=formCI:j_idt999")

    self.request = reply.request()
    #self.reply = self.manager.get(self.request)
    self.reply = self.manager.post(reply.request(), postData)

def saveExcel(self):
    f =  open('C:\\path\\to\\file\\searchResults.xls', 'wb')
    f.write(str(self.reply.readAll()))
    f.flush()
    f.close()

    self.exit()
```

The path to the file was changed here on purpose.

I tried using the post method as well as the get method (commented on the snippet above), but none of them worked, I always end up with a corrupted xls file that is really a HTML file with the source code of the page.

When I uncomment the postData item "javax.faces.ViewState", the server returns an error. I'm guessing here is the key that is missing for this, because of the special characters on this specific line.

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I know my way with python, but I'm no expert at all.

If there is any need for clarification please let me know.

I'm currently using python 2.7.9 and PyQT 4.8.7.

Comment: Can you provide a link to real website?  I would like to see the exact request generated by the submission of the form.

Comment: Also, `javax.faces.ViewState` [probably](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/jsf-viewstate-and-csrf-hacker-attacks/) holds both a CSRF (prevention) token and some state, and that's why the server refuses requests without it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide the actual link because it's a internal system of one of my clients.

I did manage to get it right, it was the special characters. I really needed the ViewState, but the "+", "/" and "=" signs on it were crashing.

Debugging on Firefox, I found that when sent, the special characters on the actual data were substituted with HTML hex codes (i.e.: %2A, %3D).


When replacing these and sending it again it worked wonderfully.

Comment: In that case, can you provide details on the requests your browser makes when you visit and submit the form?

Comment: I solved that, but thanks for sharing the knowledge on the javax.faces.ViewState, it really helped to get me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I created this piece of code:

```
def specialCharsToHtmlHex(self, rawString, jsfViewState=False):
    parsedString = (rawString.replace('+', '%2B')
                             .replace('/', '%2F')
                             .replace(':', '%3A')
                             .replace('?', '%3F'))

    if jsfViewState:
        parsedString = parsedString.replace('=', '%3D')

    return parsedString
```

I did this special treatment for the ViewState because I cant transform the "=" where they actually part of the post structure.

Then I called the code like this:

```
    postData = QByteArray()

    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX=formX&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:idSelecao_input=1&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:dataJanela_input="+self.searchData['startDate']+"&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:dataAte_input="+self.searchData['endDate']+"&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['horaJanela']+"=&")) 
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['tipoPortabilidade']+"=&")) 
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['statusBilhete']+"="+self.searchData['statusValue']+"&")) 
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['operadora']+"=0&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:produto_input="+self.searchData['productValue']+"&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:options=1&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:cpf=&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['janelaBloqueada']+"=0&")) 
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("formX:dataTable_selection=&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex("javax.faces.ViewState="+self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.searchData['jsfViewState'], jsfViewState=True)+"&"))
    postData.append(self.specialCharsToHtmlHex(self.fieldNames['mojarraHiddenInput']+"="+self.searchData['mojarraHiddenValue']))

    self.reply = self.webView.page().networkAccessManager().post(reply.request(), postData)
```

And the problem was solved, this way I got the Excel file I wanted to.

I know there is some redundancy, but I decided to keep it like this for the sake of padronization.